# Sort new column in Users wp-admin

Tags: php, users

I created a new column in the Users Admin Tab called "Listings". Each line is a number which means how many Listings an user has.

```
//// ADD THE NEW COLUMN
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'add_listing_count_column' );
function add_listing_count_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['Listings'] = 'Listings'; // 
    return $columns;}


// FILL THE NEW COLUMN
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'add_listing_count_column_row', 10, 3 );
function add_listing_count_column_row( $row_output, $column_id_attr, $user_id ) {
if ( $column_id_attr == 'Listings') {
        return count_user_posts( $user_id, 'job_listing' );
    }
    return $row_output;}
```

I want to make that column sortable.. But it keeps sorting by username... Any idea what could it be?

```
// MAKE THE NEW COLUMN SORTABLE
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'add_listing_count_column_sortable',10,3 );
function add_listing_count_column_sortable( $columns ) {
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'Listings' => 'Listings' ), $columns );
}

 add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'smartwp_sort_last_login_column' );
function smartwp_sort_last_login_column( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }
     $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( isset( $screen->id ) && $screen->id !== 'users' ) {
        return $query;
    }
     if ( isset( $_GET[ 'orderby' ] ) && $_GET[ 'orderby' ] == 'Listings' ) {
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'post_count';
    }
     return $query;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `orderby` equals `post_count`, WordPress will [always work with posts from the default post type `post`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L766). What you can do is, try to modify [that part of the query](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/ba943e113d3b31b121f77a2d30aebe14b047c69d/src/wp-includes/post.php#L6948) for this specific case.

Something like this should work:

```php
add_filter( 'query', 'smartwp_sort_last_login_column_query' );
function smartwp_sort_last_login_column_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    $orderby = isset( $_GET[ 'orderby' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'orderby' ] : false;

    if ( $orderby !== 'Listings' ) {
        return $query;
    }

    if ( stripos( $query, 'SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as post_count' ) !== false ) {
        $query = str_replace( '( post_type = \'post\' AND', '( post_type = \'job_listing\' AND', $query );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

What this does is tell WordPress to count the posts from the custom post type `job_listing`. Please note, that this only works for your specific case.

Make sure to fully test it, as this is the [query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/) hook, which is executed on **every** database query WordPress makes.

Comment: thank you! it worked :)

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as "accepted" so it may help other users.